# Is it wrong to have 2 or more UINavigationControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have some authentication view controllers that use my begin navigation controller, like so in AppDelegate.m:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic, retain) BeginViewController *beginViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic, retain) BeginNavigationController *beginNavigationController;

...

_beginViewController = [[BeginViewController alloc] init];
_beginNavigationController = [[BeginNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_beginViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = _beginNavigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

After a certain point, the user will autnenicate themselves and if there are no errors this happens:

```
ATabBarController *tab = [[ATabBarController alloc] init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tab animated:YES];
```

Then a tab bar controller init's:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, retain) InsideNavigationController *nav1;
....
@property (nonatomic, strong, retain) InsideNavigationController *nav4;

_view1 = [[AViewController alloc] init];
...
_view2 = [[DViewController alloc] init];

_nav1 = [[InsideNavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:_view1];
...
_nav4 = [[InsideNavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:_view4];
```

Is this the proper way to do things?  I wanted to have a navigation controller handle authentication and all unauthenticated views and then a navigation contoller for the tab bar after authenticating.

How do I get back to the first view controller?

Thanks.

Comment: whats with the -1 for

Comment: Not sure why the -1. Looks good to me. Each tab on the tabBarController needs to be its own Nav stack.

Comment: so use only 1 uinavigation controller then

Comment: What do you mean "per tab, yes"?

Comment: So I should use one controller per tab like I'm doing?

Comment: Yes that's best practice.

Comment: In my above statement, how do I get back to the root of the _beginNavigationController?